# For $x \in [0, 1]$, find explicit form for the $n_k$ such that $\{n_k\sqrt{2}\} \to x$.

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, fractional-part

This is inspired by the comment in
[Minimum values of the sequence $\{n\sqrt{2}\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568587/minimum-values-of-the-sequence-n-sqrt2)
that,
by  Kroneckers Approximation Theorem,
the fractional part of
$n\sqrt{2}$
is dense in $[0, 1]$.

My question is that,
given an $x \in [0,1]$,
is there an explicit construction
of a sequence
$(n_k)$ such that
$\{n_k\sqrt{2}\}
\to x$?
In particular,
an explicit function of the form
$n_k = f(k)$
would be nice.

Replace $\sqrt{2}$
by other irrationals for extra credit.

Is this easier for some 
particular class of reals?

The continued fraction
for $\sqrt{2}$
probably comes into play.

Comment: Just let $n_k = x/\sqrt{2}$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find a sequence $b_n$ that converges to $\sqrt 2$, such as
$$b_{k+1}=1+\frac 1{1+b_k},\quad b_1=1,\tag 1$$

or
$$b_k=\frac{\lfloor 10^k \sqrt 2\rfloor}{10^k}.\tag 2$$

By replacing $n_k=\dfrac 1{b_k/2}$, $(n_k)$ converges to $\dfrac 1{2\sqrt 2}$.

Therefore $\{n_k\sqrt 2\}$ converges to $x=1/2$.

Generally, for $r>0$ and $x\in[0,1)$, we find a sequence $b_n$ that converges to $\sqrt r$. Set $n_k=\dfrac {x}{b_k}$, then $\{n_k\sqrt r\}$ converges to $x$.